# Selenium accessing text within a div tag

Tags: python, selenium

I'm a bit of a beginner at Selenium, but I have managed to get hold of some of the basics. The problem is that I have a div tag with some text in it and I can't get the text out of it. I should add that I'm using Python.

The tag itself on the site in question is as follows:

```
<div class="xtb-text" id="ext-comp-1223">Displaying 1 - 25 of 184</div>
```

The text I want is the 'Displaying 1 - 25 of 184', but I can't seem to get it.

I copied the XPath of the div tag, which was as follows:

```
//*[@id="ext-comp-1223"]
```

I used this to get the element. I tried the .text method and did not get the text. In fact I tried every accessor I've seen on the web just to see if some of them gave meaningful information. They are follows:

```
print('Details for Display page info 1: ---')
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.text)
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.tag_name)
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.parent)
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.location)
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.size)

    print('Details for Display page info 2: ---')
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('text'))
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('tag_name'))
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('parent'))
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('location'))
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('size'))
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('value'))
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('innerText'))
    print(self.DisplayPageInfo.element.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

And the results are as follows:

```
Details for Display page info 1: ---
No data to display
div
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="a050377decd1cdc7fb98e80f91d8b9af")>
{'x': 1274, 'y': 646}
{'height': 18, 'width': 93}
Details for Display page info 2: ---
None
None
None
None
None
None
No data to display
No data to display
```

I did also try element.innerText and element.value, but these properties do not exist for a web element and so the code threw an exception.

I've checked the XPath several times and I'm sure it's the one I'm after. The text is right there after all, in the tag. But I just can't seem to get it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post url to the page and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question:

the element was inside a table which was dynamically generated. Because the table took a few seconds to load, the div tag was not populated when I went to access it. But when I inspected the elements later to see what I was doing wrong, of course it was populated.

As a temporary way to fix it, simply adding a sleep for a few seconds before these prints shows that the information can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `explicit wait` rather hard coded sleep. `explicit wait` will continue with the next steps as and when the condition is met (in your case div element is present) unlike sleep which will wait for the given time even after the div is present.

Below is the snippet how to use the explicit wait.

```
# make sure to add below improts
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Here is the line that will make sure the script waits for the element to present

DisplayPageInfo = (wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.xpath, locator))))
```

Try to use the class with other combinations if the element have `dynamic id`.